trying to find out the logic of this page: approx ++ 100 results stored - and parsed with Python & BS4
trying to find out the logic that is behind this page:
we have stored some results in the following db:
https://www.raiffeisen.ch/rch/de/ueber-uns/raiffeisen-gruppe/organisation/raiffeisenbanken/deutsche-schweiz.html#accordionitem_18104049731620873397
from a to z approx: 120 results or more:
which Options do we have to get the data
https://www.raiffeisen.ch/zuerich/de.html#bankselector-focus-titlebar
Raiffeisenbank Zürich
Limmatquai 68
8001Zürich
Tel. +41 43 244 78 78
zuerich@raiffeisen.ch

https://www.raiffeisen.ch/sennwald/de.html
Raiffeisenbank Sennwald
Äugstisriet 7
9466Sennwald
Tel. +41 81 750 40 40
sennwald@raiffeisen.ch
BIC/Swift Code: RAIFCH22XXX

https://www.raiffeisen.ch/basel/de/ueber-uns/engagement.html#bankselector-focus-titlebar
Raiffeisenbank Basel
St. Jakobs-Strasse 7
4052Basel
Tel. +41 61 226 27 28
basel@raiffeisen.ch

Hmm - i think that - if somehow all is encapsulated in the url-encoded block...
well i am trying to find it out - and here is my approach:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_raiffeisen_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        banks = []

        # Find all bank entries
        bank_entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='bank-entry')

        for entry in bank_entries:
            bank = {}
            bank['name'] = entry.find('h2', class_='bank-name').text.strip()
            bank['address'] = entry.find('div', class_='bank-address').text.strip()
            bank['tel'] = entry.find('div', class_='bank-tel').text.strip()
            bank['email'] = entry.find('a', class_='bank-email').text.strip()
            banks.append(bank)
        
        return banks
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve data from {url}")
        return None

url = 'https://www.raiffeisen.ch/rch/de/ueber-uns/raiffeisen-gruppe/organisation/raiffeisenbanken/deutsche-schweiz.html'
banks_data = get_raiffeisen_data(url)

for bank in banks_data:
    print(f"Name: {bank['name']}")
    print(f"Address: {bank['address']}")
    print(f"Tel: {bank['tel']}")
    print(f"Email: {bank['email']}")
    print('-' * 40)


You need to make a request for each bank, but some of the sites are hosted on raiffeisen.ch while other's are redirected to a different site (eg: lokalbank.ch). These site have completely different structures, thus you need different logic/strategy for each type of site.
Synchronous method (slow):
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json


def scrape_raiffeisen(html):
    data = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select_one('meta[name=organisationData]')
    bank = {
        'name': data.get('data-organisation-name'), 
        'address': {
            'street': data.get('data-organisation-street'),
            'zip': data.get('data-organisation-zip'),
            'city': data.get('data-organisation-city')
        },
        'tel': data.get('data-organisation-phone'),
        'email': data.get('data-organisation-mail')
    }

    return bank


def scrape_lokalbank(html):
    script = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('script', type='application/ld+json')
    data = json.loads(script.text).get('@graph')[1]
    address = data.get('address', {})

    bank = {
        'name': data.get('name'), 
        'address': {
            'street': address.get('streetAddress'),
            'zip': address.get('postalCode'),
            'city': address.get('addressLocality')
        },
        'tel': data.get('telephone'),
        'email': data.get('email')
    }

    return bank

scrapers = {'www.raiffeisen.ch': scrape_raiffeisen, 'www.lokalbank.ch': scrape_lokalbank}


url = 'https://www.raiffeisen.ch/rch/de/ueber-uns/raiffeisen-gruppe/organisation/raiffeisenbanken/deutsche-schweiz.html'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
bank_links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.accordion__itemWrapper li > a')]

banks = []
for link in bank_links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    hostname = urlparse(response.url).netloc
    scraper = scrapers.get(hostname)

    if not scraper:
        print(f'Could not find scraper for `{response.url}`')
        continue

    banks.append(scraper(response.text))


print(banks)


Asynchronous method:
For faster scraping, we can make the requests asynchronously using a library like aiohttp or httpx. I used curl_cffi:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json
import asyncio
from curl_cffi.requests import AsyncSession


def scrape_raiffeisen(html):
    data = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select_one('meta[name=organisationData]')
    bank = {
        'name': data.get('data-organisation-name'), 
        'address': {
            'street': data.get('data-organisation-street'),
            'zip': data.get('data-organisation-zip'),
            'city': data.get('data-organisation-city')
        },
        'tel': data.get('data-organisation-phone'),
        'email': data.get('data-organisation-mail')
    }

    return bank


def scrape_lokalbank(html):
    script = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find('script', type='application/ld+json')
    data = json.loads(script.text).get('@graph')[1]
    address = data.get('address', {})

    bank = {
        'name': data.get('name'), 
        'address': {
            'street': address.get('streetAddress'),
            'zip': address.get('postalCode'),
            'city': address.get('addressLocality')
        },
        'tel': data.get('telephone'),
        'email': data.get('email')
    }

    return bank

scrapers = {'www.raiffeisen.ch': scrape_raiffeisen, 'www.lokalbank.ch': scrape_lokalbank}



def get_banks():
    session = AsyncSession()

    async def scrape_bank(link):
        response = await session.get(link)
        hostname = urlparse(response.url).netloc
        scraper = scrapers.get(hostname)

        if not scraper:
            print(f'Could not find scraper for `{response.url}`')
            return

        return scraper(response.text)

    
    async def main():
        url = 'https://www.raiffeisen.ch/rch/de/ueber-uns/raiffeisen-gruppe/organisation/raiffeisenbanken/deutsche-schweiz.html'
        response = await session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        bank_links = [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.accordion__itemWrapper li > a')]

        tasks = [scrape_bank(link) for link in bank_links]
        banks = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await session.close()
        return banks
    
    return asyncio.run(main())


banks = get_banks()
print(banks)


hi there - many thanks for your awesome help - really outstanding.  I am overwhelmed. Thanks alot!! 10 Stars out of 5 possible.,...;)
